# How do I fix IF/ELSE program not displaying or sorting data?

Tags: cobol

This program have an SEQ file that it reads and is suppose to bypass all students that are graduated (Y), if Class Standing is other than first-year or second-year (1 or 2), and if their major is not programming (PGM), digital media (DIG) or Network Security (NES). My program is suppose to also do calculates, but currently I m just trying to get the data to print out in an RPT file. It is also suppose to format the Social Security Numbers (like XXX-XX-XXXX). Format Student Name: First Initial Middle Initial Last Name (like A B Brown) Then print First Yr or Second Yr. Next, what there major is. Then how many hours, points, and calculate and display their GPA.

```
Column  Field                       Type / Format 

    01-09       Social Security Number          Alphanumeric
            (no dashes in data file)
    10-21       Student Name                    Alphanumeric
            (first initial, middle initial, last name --- no spaces between these items in data file)
    26      Graduation Status               Alphanumeric
            (Y = student has graduated --- and other values of Graduation Status)
    27      Class Standing                  Alphanumeric
            (1 = first-year, 2 = second-year --- and other values of Class Standing)
    28-30       Major                       Alphanumeric
            (PGM, DIG, NES --- and other values of  Major)
            (PGM = Programming, DIG = Digital Media, and NES = Network Security)
    31-33       Credit Hours Earned             Numeric, no decimals
    34-36       Credit Points Earned                Numeric, no decimals
```

Current program:

```
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
       FILE-CONTROL.
     
           SELECT STUDENTS-FILE-IN
               ASSIGN TO 'STUDENTS.SEQ'
               ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
     
           SELECT STUDENTS-FILE-OUT
               ASSIGN TO 'STUDENTS.RPT'
               ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
     
       DATA DIVISION.
       FILE SECTION.
       FD  STUDENTS-FILE-IN.
       01  STUDENTS-RECORD-IN.
           05  SOCIAL-SECURITY-NUMBER-IN                 PIC X(9).
           05  STUDENT-NAME-IN                           PIC X(12).
           05                                            PIC X(4).
           05  GRADUATION-STATUS-IN                      PIC X.
           05  CLASS-STANDING-IN                         PIC X.
           05  MAJOR-IN                                  PIC X(3).
           05  CREDIT-HOURS-EARNED-IN                    PIC 9(3).
           05  CREDIT-POINTS-EARNED-IN                   PIC 9(3).
       
       
       FD  STUDENTS-FILE-OUT.
       01  STUDENTS-RECORD-OUT         PIC X(80).
          
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01  ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS       PIC X(3)       VALUE 'YES'.
       01  LINES-PRINTED                PIC 99         VALUE 99.
       01  PAGE-NUMBER                  PIC 99         VALUE ZERO.
       01  WS-FIRST-TIME-THRU           PIC X(3)       VALUE 'YES'.
       01  WS-GRAND-HOURS               PIC 9(3)       VALUE ZERO.
       01  WS-GRAND-POINTS              PIC 9(3)       VALUE ZERO.
       01  WS-GRAND-GPA                 PIC Z.ZZ       VALUE ZERO.
       01  WS-PRO-STUDENT               PIC ZZ         VALUE ZERO.
       01  WS-PRO-GPA-NUM               PIC ZZ         VALUE ZERO.
       01  WS-PRO-GPA-PER               PIC ZZ.Z       VALUE ZERO.
       01  WS-DIG-STUDENT               PIC ZZ         VALUE ZERO.
       01  WS-DIG-GPA-NUM               PIC ZZ         VALUE ZERO.
       01  WS-DIG-GPA-PER               PIC ZZ.Z       VALUE ZERO.
       01  WS-NES-STUDENT               PIC ZZ         VALUE ZERO.
       01  WS-NES-GPA-NUM               PIC ZZ         VALUE ZERO.
       01  WS-PRO-GPA-PER               PIC ZZ.Z       VALUE ZERO.
       
       01  WS-CURRENT-DATE-DATA.
           05  WS-CURRENT-DATE.
               10  RUN-YEAR                 PIC XX.
               10  RUN-MONTH                PIC XX.
               10  RUN-DAY                  PIC XX.
    
       01  HEADING-LINE-1.
           05                           PIC X(22)   VALUE SPACES.
           05                           PIC X(33)   VALUE '------ ----- ------- ----- ------'.
           05                           PIC X(6)    VALUE SPACES.
           05  HL-1-DATE.
               10  MONTH-2              PIC XX.
               10                       PIC X       VALUE'/'.
               10  DAY-2                PIC XX.
               10                       PIC X       VALUE'/'.
               10  YEAR-2               PIC XX.
           05                           PIC X(4)    VALUE SPACES.
           05                           PIC X(4)    VALUE 'PAGE'.
           05  HL-1-PAGE-NUMBER         PIC Z9.
    
       01  HEADING-LINE-2.
           05                           PIC X        VALUE SPACE.
           05                           PIC X(10)    VALUE 'SOC SEC NO'.
           05                           PIC X(4)     VALUE SPACES.
           05                           PIC X(12)    VALUE 'STUDENT NAME'.
           05                           PIC X(3)     VALUE SPACES.
           05                           PIC X(8)     VALUE 'STANDING'.
           05                           PIC X(4)     VALUE SPACES.
           05                           PIC X(5)     VALUE 'MAJOR'.
           05                           PIC X(10)    VALUE  SPACES.
           05                           PIC X(5)     VALUE 'HOURS'.
           05                           PIC X(2)     VALUE  SPACES.
           05                           PIC X(6)     VALUE  'POINTS'.
           05                           PIC X(5)     VALUE  SPACES.
           05                           PIC X(3)     VALUE  'GPA'.
           
       01  DETAIL-LINE.
           05                                        PIC X        VALUE SPACE.
           05  SOCIAL-SECURITY-NUMBER-OUT            PIC X(11).
               05 SSN-FIRST                          PIC X(3).
               05 SSN-FDASH                          PIC X        VALUE "-".
               05 SSN-MIDDLE                         PIC X(02).
               05 SSN-MDASH                          PIC X        VALUE "-".
               05 SSN-LAST                           PIC X(04).
           05                                        PIC X(3)     VALUE SPACES.
           05  STUDENT-NAME-OUT                      PIC X(13).
               05 FNAME                              PIC X.
               05                                    PIC X        VALUE SPACE.
               05 MNAME                              PIC X.
               05                                    PIC X        VALUE SPACE.
               05 LNAME                              PIC X(9).
           05  STANDING-OUT                          PIC X(9).
           05                                        PIC X(3)     VALUE SPACES.
           05  MAJOR-OUT                             PIC X(13).
           05                                        PIC X(4)     VALUE SPACES.
           05  HOURS-OUT                             PIC X(2).
           05                                        PIC X(5)     VALUE SPACES.
           05  POINTS-OUT                            PIC X(3).
           05                                        PIC X(4)     VALUE SPACES.
           05  STUDENT-GPA-OUT                       PIC 9.99.
           
       01  TOTALS-LINE.
           05                      PIC X          VALUE SPACE.
           05                      PIC X(6)       VALUE 'TOTALS'.
           05                      PIC X(50)      VALUE SPACES.
           05  TL-GRAND-HOURS      PIC Z,ZZZ.
           05                      PIC X(2)      VALUE SPACES.
           05  TL-GRAND-POINTS     PIC ZZ,ZZZ.
           05                      PIC X(4)       VALUE SPACES.
           05  TL-GRAND-GPA        PIC 9.99.
           
       01  TOTALS-LINE-2A.
           05                      PIC X          VALUE SPACE.
           05                      PIC X(19)      VALUE 'PROGRAMMING MAJORS:'.
           
       01  TOTALS-LINE-2B.
           05                          PIC X(5)       VALUE SPACES.
           05                          PIC X(18)      VALUE 'NUMBER OF STUDENTS'.
           05                          PIC X(9)       VALUE SPACES.
           05  TL-GRAND-PRO-STUDENT    PIC X(2).    
           
       01  TOTALS-LINE-2C.
           05                          PIC X(5)       VALUE SPACES.
           05                          PIC X(21)      VALUE 'NUMBER WITH GPA > 3.0'.
           05                          PIC X(7)       VALUE SPACES.
           05  TL-GRAND-PRO-NUM-GPA    PIC X.
           
       01  TOTALS-LINE-2D.
           05                          PIC X(5)       VALUE SPACES.
           05                          PIC X(22)      VALUE 'PERCENT WITH GPA > 3.0'.
           05                          PIC X(5)       VALUE SPACES.
           05  TL-GRAND-PRO-GPA-PER    PIC ZZ.9.
       
       01  TOTALS-LINE-3A.
           05                      PIC X          VALUE SPACE.
           05                      PIC X(21)      VALUE 'DIGITAL MEDIA MAJORS:'.
           
       01  TOTALS-LINE-3B.
           05                          PIC X(5)       VALUE SPACES.
           05                          PIC X(18)      VALUE 'NUMBER OF STUDENTS'.
           05                          PIC X(9)       VALUE SPACES.
           05  TL-GRAND-DIG-STUDENT    PIC X(2).    
           
       01  TOTALS-LINE-3C.
           05                          PIC X(5)       VALUE SPACES.
           05                          PIC X(21)      VALUE 'NUMBER WITH GPA > 3.0'.
           05                          PIC X(7)       VALUE SPACES.
           05  TL-GRAND-DIG-NUM-GPA    PIC X.
           
       01  TOTALS-LINE-3D.
           05                          PIC X(5)       VALUE SPACES.
           05                          PIC X(22)      VALUE 'PERCENT WITH GPA > 3.0'.
           05                          PIC X(5)       VALUE SPACES.
           05  TL-GRAND-DIG-GPA-PER    PIC ZZ.9.
           
       01  TOTALS-LINE-4A.
           05                      PIC X          VALUE SPACE.
           05                      PIC X(24)      VALUE 'NETWORK SECURITY MAJORS:'.
           
       01  TOTALS-LINE-4B.
           05                          PIC X(5)       VALUE SPACES.
           05                          PIC X(18)      VALUE 'NUMBER OF STUDENTS'.
           05                          PIC X(9)       VALUE SPACES.
           05  TL-GRAND-NET-STUDENT    PIC X(2).    
           
       01  TOTALS-LINE-4C.
           05                          PIC X(5)       VALUE SPACES.
           05                          PIC X(21)      VALUE 'NUMBER WITH GPA > 3.0'.
           05                          PIC X(7)       VALUE SPACES.
           05  TL-GRAND-NET-NUM-GPA    PIC X.
           
       01  TOTALS-LINE-4D.
           05                          PIC X(5)       VALUE SPACES.
           05                          PIC X(22)      VALUE 'PERCENT WITH GPA > 3.0'.
           05                          PIC X(5)       VALUE SPACES.
           05  TL-GRAND-NET-GPA-PER    PIC ZZ.9.
           
       
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       100-MAIN.
           OPEN INPUT STUDENTS-FILE-IN
           OPEN OUTPUT STUDENTS-FILE-OUT
           
           ACCEPT WS-CURRENT-DATE FROM DATE
           MOVE RUN-MONTH TO MONTH-2
           MOVE RUN-DAY TO DAY-2
           MOVE RUN-YEAR TO YEAR-2
           PERFORM 300-WRITE-HEADINGS
           
           PERFORM UNTIL ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS = 'NO'
               READ STUDENTS-FILE-IN
                   AT END
                       PERFORM 400-TOTALS-ROUTINE
                       MOVE 'NO ' TO ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS
                   NOT AT END
                       PERFORM 200-PROCESS-ONE-RECORD
               END-READ
           END-PERFORM
     
           CLOSE STUDENTS-FILE-IN
           CLOSE STUDENTS-FILE-OUT
           STOP RUN.
     
       200-PROCESS-ONE-RECORD.
           IF LINES-PRINTED > 53
               PERFORM 300-WRITE-HEADINGS
           END-IF
           IF GRADUATION-STATUS-IN IS NOT EQUAL TO 'Y'
           CONTINUE
           IF CLASS-STANDING-IN IS EQUAL TO '1' OR '2'
           CONTINUE
           IF MAJOR-IN IS EQUAL TO 'PGM' OR 'NES' OR 'DIG'
           END-IF
           MOVE SOCIAL-SECURITY-NUMBER-IN TO SOCIAL-SECURITY-NUMBER-OUT     
           MOVE STUDENT-NAME-IN TO STUDENT-NAME-OUT
           IF CLASS-STANDING-IN IS EQUAL TO '1'
               MOVE 'First Yr' TO STANDING-OUT
           IF CLASS-STANDING-IN IS EQUAL TO '2'
               MOVE 'Second Yr' TO STANDING-OUT
           END-IF
           IF MAJOR-IN IS EQUAL TO 'PGM'
               MOVE 'Programming' TO MAJOR-OUT
           IF MAJOR-IN IS EQUAL TO 'NES'
               MOVE 'Net Security' TO MAJOR-OUT
           IF MAJOR-IN IS EQUAL TO 'DIG'
               MOVE 'Digital Media' TO MAJOR-OUT
           END-IF
           MOVE CREDIT-HOURS-EARNED-IN TO HOURS-OUT
           MOVE CREDIT-POINTS-EARNED-IN TO POINTS-OUT
           MOVE DETAIL-LINE TO STUDENTS-RECORD-OUT
           WRITE STUDENTS-RECORD-OUT
               AFTER ADVANCING 2 LINES
           ADD 2 TO LINES-PRINTED
           COMPUTE WS-GRAND-HOURS = WS-GRAND-HOURS + CREDIT-HOURS-EARNED-IN
           COMPUTE WS-GRAND-POINTS = WS-GRAND-POINTS + CREDIT-POINTS-EARNED-IN
           COMPUTE WS-GRAND-GPA ROUNDED = WS-GRAND-HOURS / WS-GRAND-POINTS.
               
       300-WRITE-HEADINGS.
           ADD 1 TO PAGE-NUMBER
           MOVE PAGE-NUMBER TO HL-1-PAGE-NUMBER
           MOVE HEADING-LINE-1 TO STUDENTS-RECORD-OUT
           
           IF WS-FIRST-TIME-THRU = 'YES'
               WRITE STUDENTS-RECORD-OUT
               MOVE 'NO' TO WS-FIRST-TIME-THRU
           ELSE
               WRITE STUDENTS-RECORD-OUT AFTER ADVANCING PAGE
           END-IF
               
           MOVE HEADING-LINE-2 TO STUDENTS-RECORD-OUT
           WRITE STUDENTS-RECORD-OUT
               AFTER ADVANCING 1
           MOVE 3 TO LINES-PRINTED.
           
       400-TOTALS-ROUTINE.
           IF LINES-PRINTED > 53
               PERFORM 300-WRITE-HEADINGS
           END-IF
           MOVE WS-GRAND-HOURS TO TL-GRAND-HOURS
           MOVE WS-GRAND-POINTS TO TL-GRAND-POINTS
           MOVE WS-GRAND-GPA TO TL-GRAND-GPA
           MOVE TOTALS-LINE TO STUDENTS-RECORD-OUT
           WRITE STUDENTS-RECORD-OUT AFTER ADVANCING 3 LINES
           ADD 2 TO LINES-PRINTED.
```

Current RPT output file:

```
                      ------ ----- ------- ----- ------      03/03/21    PAGE 1

 SOC SEC NO    STUDENT NAME   STANDING    MAJOR          HOURS  POINTS     GPA


 TOTALS                                                                   0.00
```

Needs RPT file needs to print like:

```
                      ------ ----- ------- ----- ------      03/03/21  PAGE  1

 SOC SEC NO    STUDENT NAME   STANDING    MAJOR          HOURS  POINTS     GPA

 377-65-8797   M J Abbott     First Yr    Digital Media     21      70    3.33
 445-90-3241   J C Armour     Second Yr   Programming       59     140    2.37
 877-39-5401   K F Ault       First Yr    Net Security      44     132    3.00
 980-44-3254   R L Bishop     First Yr    Net Security      20      62    3.10
 307-54-8872   D R Boyer      Second Yr   Digital Media     55     168    3.05
 345-21-3465   R D Byers      First Yr    Net Security      10      24    2.40
 659-87-6655   S A Campbell   Second Yr   Programming       66     180    2.73
 907-88-3271   D E Copeland   Second Yr   Net Security      67     202    3.01
 387-78-9843   K D Curtis     Second Yr   Programming       55     160    2.91
 887-65-8341   R M Davis      First Yr    Programming       40     119    2.98
 477-80-9325   D P Donaldson  First Yr    Digital Media      5      12    2.40
 207-55-9801   A L Duffy      First Yr    Net Security      23      75    3.26
 399-82-3781   A F Edwards    Second Yr   Net Security      66     261    3.95
 345-32-1092   M L Evans      Second Yr   Digital Media     70     201    2.87
 768-43-2214   W S Ewing      First Yr    Programming       21      44    2.10
 335-76-9801   A C Farkas     Second Yr   Programming       80     241    3.01
 555-87-9214   T E Frail      First Yr    Digital Media      1       3    3.00
 609-95-4386   R L Fuller     Second Yr   Net Security      88     352    4.00
 872-11-9903   J M Garcia     Second Yr   Digital Media     65     190    2.92
 847-64-3902   R S Gordon     First Yr    Programming        5      17    3.40
 675-50-9821   S L Guthrie    First Yr    Programming       22      88    4.00
 226-54-7855   R L Hartman    First Yr    Net Security     111     440    3.96
 448-82-3177   G C Hill       Second Yr   Programming       87     169    1.94
 598-87-3240   W E Hyde       Second Yr   Programming       55     159    2.89
 389-55-7430   H P Ickes      First Yr    Net Security      18      56    3.11
 499-08-7112   D L Imler      Second Yr   Net Security      74     209    2.82
 299-00-6573   R D Isley      First Yr    Digital Media     10      39    3.90
 776-04-4879   H L Jackson    First Yr    Digital Media     42     108    2.57
 899-01-2845   K M Joseph     Second Yr   Programming       88     260    2.95
 176-59-0831   D L Justice    Second Yr   Digital Media     76     230    3.03
 769-94-1659   F D Kahle      Second Yr   Digital Media     79     240    3.04
 307-98-5332   E S Kirk       First Yr    Programming        9      16    1.78
 387-95-6422   D A Koch       Second Yr   Net Security      63     222    3.52
 822-43-8009   S R Laman      Second Yr   Net Security      80     240    3.00
 078-96-5516   C J Lott       First Yr    Programming        9      30    3.33
 188-64-3487   P T Lyons      First Yr    Programming       45     136    3.02
 307-88-4251   J A McDonnell  First Yr    Net Security       9      28    3.11
 598-77-4365   S B Miller     Second Yr   Digital Media     86     249    2.90
 218-87-9563   L R Nickles    First Yr    Net Security      44     144    3.27
 345-90-1226   R J Nunn       First Yr    Programming       32      99    3.09
 465-58-9021   R T O'Brien    Second Yr   Digital Media     88     352    4.00
 774-65-8832   D E Osborne    Second Yr   Digital Media     76     228    3.00
 489-97-6092   R V Parent     Second Yr   Net Security      66     200    3.03
 783-22-5185   D W Price      Second Yr   Programming       78     228    2.92
 999-04-7621   S D Queen      First Yr    Programming       20      60    3.00
 836-61-9047   N C Quinn      First Yr    Digital Media     44     133    3.02
 657-73-2064   D W Rabe       Second Yr   Digital Media     99     381    3.85
 227-68-9014   D L Robinson   First Yr    Programming       38     113    2.97
 376-65-9081   L A Smith      Second Yr   Net Security     112     336    3.00
 117-98-0236   J I Taylor     First Yr    Net Security      42     127    3.02
 988-72-5701   L R Truman     Second Yr   Programming      100     380    3.80
 430-95-7205   N H Underwood  Second Yr   Net Security      98     392    4.00  
                      RHODES STATE COLLEGE GRADE REPORT      10/11/12  PAGE  2

 SOC SEC NO    STUDENT NAME   STANDING    MAJOR          HOURS  POINTS     GPA

 309-44-7620   L J Uzelac     First Yr    Programming       23      72    3.13
 467-09-8853   C A Valenti    First Yr    Programming       10      10    1.00
 988-32-0851   H E Vorhees    Second Yr   Net Security      21      68    3.24
 598-83-2016   C L Wagner     First Yr    Digital Media     29      88    3.03
 699-38-7440   L S Wood       Second Yr   Net Security      60     177    2.95
 499-02-1987   J A Yant       First Yr    Net Security      42     127    3.02
 399-78-0041   R E Young      Second Yr   Digital Media    111     333    3.00
 498-37-6022   R J Zellers    Second Yr   Digital Media     90     360    4.00
 984-00-2164   R T Zuber      Second Yr   Programming       88     266    3.02

 Totals                                                  3,235  10,246    3.17



 Programming Majors:
     Number of students         22
     Number with GPA > 3.0       9
     Percent with GPA > 3.0     40.9%

 Digital Media Majors:
     Number of students         18
     Number with GPA > 3.0      10
     Percent with GPA > 3.0     55.6%

 Network Security Majors:
     Number of students         21
     Number with GPA > 3.0      15
     Percent with GPA > 3.0     71.4%
```

SEQ file:

```
675509821SLGuthrie        1PGM022088
226547855RLHartman        1NES111440
448823177GCHill           2PGM087169
598873240WEHyde           2PGM055159
389557430HPIckes          1NES018056
499087112DLImler          2NES074209
299006573RDIsley          1DIG010039
776044879HLJackson       X1DIG042108
899012845KMJoseph         2PGM088260
176590831DLJustice        2DIG076230
769941659FDKahle          2DIG079240
307985332ESKirk           1PGM009016
387956422DAKoch           2NES063222
822438009SRLaman          2NES080240
409875621KRLester          DIG065190
078965516CJLott           1PGM009030
188643487PTLyons          1PGM045136
307884251JAMcDonnell      1NES009028
598774365SBMiller         2DIG086249
218879563LRNickles        1NES044144
345901226RJNunn           1PGM032099
465589021RTO'Brien        2DIG088352
774658832DEOsborne        2DIG076228
489976092RVParent         2NES066200
783225185DWPrice          2PGM078228
999047621SDQueen          1PGM020060
836619047NCQuinn          1DIG044133
657732064DWRabe           2DIG099381
227689014DLRobinson       1PGM038113
848769033PBSadler         1COR008030
376659081LASmith          2NES112336
117980236JITaylor         1NES042127
988725701LRTruman         2PGM100380
430957205NHUnderwood      2NES098392
309447620LJUzelac         1PGM023072
467098853CAValenti        1PGM010010
988320851HEVorhees        2NES021068
598832016CLWagner         1DIG029088
699387440LSWood           2NES060177
499021987JAYant           1NES042127
399780041REYoung          2DIG111333
498376022RJZellers        2DIG090360
231442095JBZink           0PGM090360
984002164RTZuber          2PGM088266
```

Comment: What _specifically_ are you having trouble with? Your program has a number of `IF` statements. Please fix the post so that it includes a [mcve], i.e. the _minimum_ required to reproduce whatever issue you're having, and also explain what that issue is, i.e. what _precisely_ does the code do now, how _precisely_ is that different from what you want, and what _exactly_ is it you need help with.

Comment: My problem is when trying to sort through the SEQ none of the data prints into the RPT file, only my header, page number, and data print. So how do I properly read the SEQ and get it to print in the RPT file? This is why I attached the current RPT file and what the RPT file should look like.

Comment: Do not use the comments to provide clarifications, **[edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66466536/edit) to fix any deficiencies.** And pay close attention to the comments requesting clarifications and improvements, so that you ensure your edits actually do improve the post.

Comment: Other than: The question really needs a cleanup to match Stockoverflow: you have  a bunch of `IF` without indentation (and without matching `END-IF`), you may solve the problem when fixing those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cobol `if` statements must be explicitly ended by either a `end-if` or .

So

```
       IF MAJOR-IN IS EQUAL TO 'PGM'
           MOVE 'Programming' TO MAJOR-OUT
       IF MAJOR-IN IS EQUAL TO 'NES'
           MOVE 'Net Security' TO MAJOR-OUT
       IF MAJOR-IN IS EQUAL TO 'DIG'
           MOVE 'Digital Media' TO MAJOR-OUT
       END-IF
       MOVE CREDIT-HOURS-EARNED-IN TO HOURS-OUT
       MOVE CREDIT-POINTS-EARNED-IN TO POINTS-OUT
       MOVE DETAIL-LINE TO STUDENTS-RECORD-OUT
       WRITE STUDENTS-RECORD-OUT
           AFTER ADVANCING 2 LINES
       ADD 2 TO LINES-PRINTED
```

indented properly would be

```
       IF MAJOR-IN IS EQUAL TO 'PGM'
           MOVE 'Programming' TO MAJOR-OUT
           IF MAJOR-IN IS EQUAL TO 'NES'
              MOVE 'Net Security' TO MAJOR-OUT
              IF MAJOR-IN IS EQUAL TO 'DIG'
                 MOVE 'Digital Media' TO MAJOR-OUT
              END-IF
              MOVE CREDIT-HOURS-EARNED-IN TO HOURS-OUT
              MOVE CREDIT-POINTS-EARNED-IN TO POINTS-OUT
              MOVE DETAIL-LINE TO STUDENTS-RECORD-OUT
              WRITE STUDENTS-RECORD-OUT
                 AFTER ADVANCING 2 LINES
```

The only way `student record` will be written is if
MAJOR-IN = 'PGM' and MAJOR-IN = 'NES' at the same time which is impossible so nothing is written.

This is just one of the problems in the program, I will leave you to apply similar fixes through out the program

---

Also `CONTINUE` means do nothing, so is pointless in this code as written

```
       IF GRADUATION-STATUS-IN IS NOT EQUAL TO 'Y'
       CONTINUE
       IF CLASS-STANDING-IN IS EQUAL TO '1' OR '2'
       CONTINUE
       IF MAJOR-IN IS EQUAL TO 'PGM' OR 'NES' OR 'DIG'
       END-IF
```

Work out you want the code to do and fix it.